fetching named ranges values based on values string references in a table column
In a workbook, I have sheets that look like this:

The sheets I'm concerned with extracting data from follow a naming convention, where the sheet names are pre-fixed with 'd_'.
Additionally, in the above, there are local named ranges for:

tbl_pr: named range for the entire table highlighted by the border above, with columns 'month, date, gross'
tot_{jan}: named range for each month total row (i.e. Jan Total=jan_total named range, Feb Total = feb_total, etc)
tot_qtr{1}: named range for each qtr total row (Qtr1 Total = qtr1_total)
employee_name: named range for the name of the person
SSN: named range for the SSN

Using power query, for every sheet that begins with 'd_', I would like to extract and show a table consisting of columns:
Name, SSN, Qtr1, Qtr2, Qtr3, Qtr4
For the Qtr# rows, I need just the cell in the 'Gross' column.
I googled on how to iterate sheets in power query and extract data, but not much. Best I can find was this: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Looping-though-tabs-or-tables-to-extract-data-from-excel-files/m-p/932205
So as my very first attempt at trying to understand power query. What I've learned is it is impossible to get the sheet name from the current workbook. So instead, you have to open and read the contents of an external file.  Here is what I have so far
let
    'read file
    curr_year=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="curr_year"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
     payroll_file = Text.Replace("Z:\onedrive\{year}\{year} pr.xlsm", "{year}", Number.ToText(curr_year)),
    tbl1 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(payroll_file), null, true),
    'filter for only sheet we are interested
    emp_sheets = Table.SelectRows(tbl1, each [Kind] = "Sheet" and Text.StartsWith([Name], "d_") and [Name] <> "d_tmplt"),
    
    'generate employee named range reference by concatenating sheet name + 'employee_name'
    emp_nr_added = Table.AddColumn(emp_sheets, "emp_nr", each [Item] & "!employee_name"),
    'now try to fetch the named range
    emp_nr_val =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = each emp_nr_added[emp_nr]]}[Content]{0}[Column1]

in
    emp_nr_val


This fails when trying to fetch the named range value
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
Details:
    Key=[Record]
    Table=[Table]

I have confirmed that the named range exist and I can reference them manually via a standard excel equation ("={sheetname}!employee_name")
Also, after solving this, I think I need to do an Index/Match to get the Qtr gross cell, not quite sure yet how I will do that w/ power query.
Any help much appreciated
EDIT 1
As a test, I have converted the last two lines to:
   'create a list
    emp_nr_lst = Table.AddColumn(emp_sheets, "emp_nr", each [Item] & "!employee_name")[emp_nr],
    'test that a named range lookup works for first item in list
    emp_nr_val =  Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = List.First(emp_nr_lst)]}[Content]

This works, it returns the value at the range for the first item in the list.  The question is how do I iterate a list? I've tried a 100 and two versions of each on em_nrs, none work. I always get the same error noted above.
EDIT 2
I can get the named range value finally..after many attempts i settled on this:
Custom function:
let get_nr=(nr) =>
    let
        name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=nr]}[Content],
        value = name{0}[Column1]
    in
        value
in get_nr

Generate a table, add name range reference, add column by using named range reference column to look up value:
let
    //read file
    curr_year=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="curr_year"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
     payroll_file = Text.Replace("Z:\onedrive\{year}\{year} pr.xlsm", "{year}", Number.ToText(curr_year)),
    tbl_wrkbk = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(payroll_file), null, true),

    //filter sheets
    emp_sheets = Table.SelectRows(tbl_wrkbk, each [Kind] = "Sheet" and Text.StartsWith([Name], "d_") and [Name] <> "d_tmplt"),
    //generate named range reference by concatenating sheet name + 'employee_name'
    em_nrs = Table.AddColumn(emp_sheets, "emp_nr", each [Item] & "!employee_name"),
    //call custom function to get named range
    tbl_out = Table.AddColumn(em_nrs, "get_nr", each get_nr([emp_nr]))
in 
   tbl_out

So I know I can get the SSN and Employee name columns added now.  Now I'm need help in figuring out how I can look up the intersection of the Gross column + a named range (i.e., qtr1_total, qtr2_total)

This seems to have an approach for querying worksheets: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Consolidating-multiple-files-different-sheet-names/td-p/2979283

@TimWilliams Thanks but i can not get their example to work. for example i converted by filter for list of sheets to #"matches" = tbl1{[Name Starts With "d_" and Name  <> "d_tmplt", Kind = "Sheet"]}[Data],, but the editor complains that 'Name' is an invalid identifier.

also what does "#" prefix mean for the variable? is that just a way to use named variable with spaces or does it have other meanings?

also im not sure that link is addressing the error im seeing above - i think it doing what i have already done, which is generate a table by filtering sheet names based on patterns.  that i have done (though differently than how that link is doing it).  i've also added a  new column to that table with a string representation of a named range for each row in the table.  now i need to fetch the value at that named row and add them to the table.
